# IE-only css affect only the page in IE, and not in other browsers

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-chrome

My webpage that I am working on works fine in other browsers except IE. I am using IE 10 (the preview version) so I can use shadows, and the `<br />` isn't working so I made an IE-specific css so that if the browser is IE, it loads the IE css. Well, when I go to change the margins for the .homepagetable, it also applies the css to the other browsers. The difference between main.css and all-ie-only.css is the .homepagetable.

Index.php

```
    <? include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>
    <?
    $reg = @$_POST['reg'];
    //declaring variables to prevent errors
    $fn = ""; //First Name
    $ln = ""; //Last Name
    $un = ""; //Username
    $em = ""; //Email
    $em2 = ""; //Email 2
    $pswd = ""; //Password
    $pswd2 = ""; //Password 2
    $d = ""; //Sign up Date
    $u_check = ""; //Check if username exists
    //registration form
    $fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
    $ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
    $un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
    $em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
    $em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
    $pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
    $pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
    $d = date("y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day

    if ($reg) {
    if ($em==$em2) {
    // Check if user already exists
    $u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
    // Count the amount of rows where username = $un
    $check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
    if ($check == 0) {
    //check all of the fields have been filled in
    if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
    // check that passwords match
    if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
    // check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
    if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
    echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
    }
    else
    {
    // check the length of the password is between 5 and 30 characters long
    if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
    echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
    }
    else
    {
    //encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
    $pswd = md5($pswd);
    $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','d','0')");
    die("<h2>Welcome to Rebel Connect</h2>Login to your account to get started.");
    }
    }
    }
    else {
    echo "Your passwords don't match!";
    }
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "Please fill in all fields";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Username already taken.";
    }
    }
    else {
    echo "Your e-mails don't match!";
    }
    }
    ?>
    <?
    //Login Script
    if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
        $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
        $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
        $password_login=md5($password_login);
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
        //Check for their existance
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
        if ($userCount == 1) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $id = $row["id"];
        }
             $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
             $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
             $_Session["password_login"] = $password_login;
             exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
             } else {
             echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
             exit();
        }
    }
    ?>
    <table class="homepageTable">
            <tr>
                <td width="60%" valign="top">
                 <h2>Already a member? Login below.</h2>
                 <form action="index.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
                    <input type="text" size="25" name="user_login" id="user_login" placeholder="username" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="password" size="25" name="password_login" id="password_login" placeholder="password" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Login to your account!">
                 </form>
                </td>
                <td width="40%" valign="top">
                 <h2>Sign up below...</h2>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<? echo $fn; ?>">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<? echo $ln; ?>">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<? echo $un; ?>">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<? echo $em; ?>">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Re-enter Email" value="<? echo $em2; ?>">
                <input type="password" size="25" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<? echo $pswd; ?>">
                <input type="password" size="25" name="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" value="<? echo $pswd2; ?>"><br />
                <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>

header.inc.php

<?
include ("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {

}
else
{
header("location: home.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<if !IE>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<if IE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all-ie-only.css" />
<title>Rebel Reach - PHS Student Social Network</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerMenu">
      <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                  <img src="img/find_friends_logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="search_box">
                  <form method="get" action="search.php" id="search">
                  <input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search..." />
                  </form>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
                  <a href="#">About</a>
                  <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                  <a href="#">Login</a>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

main.css

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #eff5f9
}
.headerMenu {
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    height: 56px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 125px;
}
.logo img {
    padding-top: 7px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 38px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
}
.search_box {
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    border:inset 2px
}
#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(../img/search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #666;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(../img/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 350px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
@media screen and (max-width:1280px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        margin-right: 6%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1400px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1920px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 25%;
    }
}
#menu a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg_hover_mouse_over.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #0084C6;
}
input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline:none;
}
input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0084C6;
}
input[type="password"] {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline:none;
}
input[type="password"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0084C6;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #006fc4;
    border: 1px solid #00508d;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.homepageTable {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

all-ie-only.css

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #eff5f9
}
.headerMenu {
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    height: 56px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 125px;
}
.logo img {
    padding-top: 7px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 38px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
}
.search_box {
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    border:inset 2px
}
#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(../img/search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #666;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(../img/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 350px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1280px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        margin-right: 6%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1400px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1920px) {
    #menu {
        background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        height: 37px;
        padding-top: 19px;
        margin-right: 25%;
    }
}
#menu a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image:url(../img/menu_bg_hover_mouse_over.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #0084C6;
    clear: both;
}
input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline:none;
}
input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0084C6;
}
input[type="password"] {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline:none;
}
input[type="password"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0084C6;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #006fc4;
    border: 1px solid #00508d;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.homepageTable {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: warning: your code is highly vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, and has a number of other obvious security flaws. Also, please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated; it is recommended to switch to the newer `mysqli` or `PDO` libs instead.

Comment: I haven't finished writing it yet, and it is just for my senior project. I am building a social network, and it is just to be a product, and will probably not be used on the internet except for a day, in which nothing important will be stored on. @SDC

Comment: Have you googled "ie-only stylesheet"? There's plenty there. Also, just a tip: you don't need to repeat all the other stuff. You can have one main stylesheet, and then one for IE that overrides only what is needed

Comment: @naomi I have, and I tried using some of them, and they work to the extent of loading the ie-specific.css, but when the browser is google, it still loads the ie-specific.css. It doesn't load the main.css.

Comment: It actually loads both. Your syntax is invalid.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - fair enough; but if you're learning PHP, you really need to be aware of it. If it was my coursework, I wouldn't want to be learning techniques that were obsolete before I even started.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - no worries. And I hope I didn't come across as rude either. I'll leave it at that, but if you do want to learn more about modern PHP techniques, a good place to start is http://phpbestpractices.org/. Hope the project goes well.  :-)

Comment: @SDC which would you say is better? `PDO` or `mysqli` and thanks again! I deleted my other comment because it was irrelevant to the question haha but at least you saw it before it got deleted

Comment: @SDC how do I go about implementing PDO instead of mysql (I'm about to post another question for it)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - PDO is better than mysqli. Iif you have existing mysql_xx() code, mysqli is easier to convert to, but for new code, I'd go with PDO every time. Re how to implement it, it's a big topic, so a new question would be better than me answering here. The site I linked earlier has some info, and also links to further references. And here's another link that might be helpful: http://phpmaster.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-2/

Comment: @sdc thanks for that link. I'm going to make a new question, and what I might start doing is making a new file and just comparing what i have with mysql and then writing it with pdo in the new file

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a good place to start. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely listen to @SDC's comment regarding security flaws. That's a far more significant issue than cross-browser compatibility.

Aside from that, your code isn't working because this:

```
<if !IE>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<if IE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all-ie-only.css" />
```

isn't valid.

IE10 should be compliant with the same standards as other browsers. It sounds like IE10 is running in quirks mode at the moment. Dropping a `<!DOCTYPE>` in immediately before your `<html>` should fix the problem. Then, you don't need to use your conditionals.

If you're still stuck on the idea of using conditionals, try something like:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But, this includes both `main.css` and `all-ie-only.css`.

Comment: I will go in and try to implement the security updates, might take some time though. And for the `<!DOCTYPE>`, do I need to clarify what type of document it is, and if so, do I put php? Thanks for the help by the way. One other question. The shadows in the css make the text the same color as the background of the search box in IE, but in Chrome they don't. How do I change that? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: I went to developer tools and took it out of quirks because even though I had `<!DOCTYPE>` before `<html>` it still loaded into quirks